# How to print all file names in a folder with awk or bash?

Tags: bash, awk

I would like to print all file names in a folder.How can I do this with awk or bash?

Comment: Why do you want to do it with `awk`? It is not particularly suited for the job, whereas either the shell or Perl are.

Comment: Not sure if I understand correctly, why not just `ls`?

Comment: I think because ls will show directories as well

Comment: @xception It's easy to exclude dirs & symbolic links: `ls -l | egrep -v "^d|^l" `

Comment: I guess I just love find more :)

Comment: Another: `echo *` (it will show directories and special files along with regular files - just like `ls`). Use `find` - it's the best.

Answer (score 6):

```
ls -l /usr/bin | awk '{ print $NF }'
```

:)

Comment: I was looking for _how to list files using awk_ and run in into this - and this fails when filename has a space in it. I'll just leave a mental `--` as you seem to have exactly 404 points as is.

Answer (score 4):

```
find . -type f -maxdepth 1
```

exclude the -maxdepth part if you want to also do it recursively for subdirectories

Answer (score 3):

Following is a pure-AWK option:

```
gawk '
    BEGINFILE {
        print "Processing " FILENAME
    };
' *
```

It may be helpful if you want to use it as part of a bigger AWK script processing multiple files and you want to log which file is currently being processed.

Comment: Maybe add a `nextfile` to avoid further processing.

Answer (score 1):

This command will print all the file names:

```
for f in *; do echo "$f"; done
```

or (even shorter)

```
printf '%s\n' *
```

Alternatively, if you like to print specific file types (e.g., `.txt`), you can try this:

```
for f in *.txt; do echo "$f"; done
```

or (even shorter)

```
printf '%s\n' *.txt
```

Comment: I would do more something like `for f in *; do [ -f $f ] && echo "$f"; done`

Answer (score 0):

/bin/ls does this job for you and you may call it from bash.

```
$> /bin/ls
[.. List of files..]
```

Interpreting your question you might be interested in iterating over every single file in this directory. This can be done using bash as well:

```
for f in `ls`; do
   echo $f;
done
```

Comment: No need for `ls` in your `for` loop. Just use globbing: `for f in *`

Comment: @xception: I figured that's what the questioner wanted. Might be wrong, though.

Answer (score 0):

```
for f in *; do var=`find "$f" | wc -l`; echo "$f: $var"; done
```

This will print name of the directory and number of files in it. `wc -l` here returns count of files +1 (Including directory)

Sample output:

```
aa: 4 
bb: 4 
cc: 1 
test2.sh: 1
```